# Twitter Bootstrap - Margins between columns and equal heights

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am creating a simple layout using Twitter Bootstrap 3.  Here is what I have so far

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-3 red">
            <h3>Column 1 Content</h3>
            <img class="img-responsive" src="http://dummyimage.com/300x400/000/fff">
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-3 blue">
            <h3>Column 2 Content</h3>
                        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://dummyimage.com/300x600/000/fff">
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-3 green">
            <h3>Column 3 Content</h3>
                        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://dummyimage.com/300x100/000/fff">
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-3 yellow">
            <h3>Column 4 Content</h3>
            <p>This is some dummy content</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5L8w6zr0/

What I am trying to do now is the following...

- Each column should be the same height
- There should be a space in between each column

I have tried to achieve the space by adding a margin to each column but that just pushes things onto the next row.

Can anyone suggest a solution?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I make Bootstrap columns all the same height?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19695784/how-can-i-make-bootstrap-columns-all-the-same-height)

Answer (score 2):

Bootstrap uses padding inside of the column elements rather than margins, so you'd want to wrap a `div` around the contents and move the color classes to that inner `div`.

See this answer for the height issue: [How can I make Bootstrap columns all the same height?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19695784/how-can-i-make-bootstrap-columns-all-the-same-height)

Answer (score 2):

What you need is a table like layout, because your columns need to be of same height, so I would suggest  using `display:table` for container, `display: table-row` for `.row` and `display: table-cell` for your cols.

If your layout needs s to break after certain point then for small screens you rewrite the display properties using media queries

[Here's an update fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5L8w6zr0/2/)

Comment: Thanks, that works.  Seems strange that there is no functionality built into bootstrap for this

Comment: @fightstarr20 Because it's not really compatible with the rest of the current float-based grid system.